# I Can't Read registry values from a service

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, registry

Within my service i have the following function in order to take some values from my registry:

```
 Public Function GetKeyValue(ByVal nKey As String, ByVal sPath As String) As String
        Dim RegKey As RegistryKey
        Dim kValue As String = Nothing
        Dim Pos As String
        If CheckRegistry(sPath) Then
            Try
                RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(sPath)
                kValue = CStr(RegKey.GetValue(nKey))

            Catch ex As Exception
                StartLogFile(" GetKeyValue " & vbNewLine & "Stack Trace= " & ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Warning)
            End Try
        End If
        Return kValue
    End Function
```

the same function works fine within a Windows form, but if i call from a service then she can't read the value.
Is there anybody how knows what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not store your data in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` but under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` that makes more sense for a Windows-Service.

Be also aware that you can also set Permissions on Registry Keys. Check also that when try reading.

Comment: If you do this then users will not be able to write to this location. That may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: and @David. Your assistance it was more than grate, the solution was the `HKLM` , it cover the functionality and the security more than ever. I wish to have the abilty to give more credits but I have only one to give. And I'm giving it with all of my hart. Thanks to all. Vote my question if you want it.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost surely reading registry settings of a different user. The service likely runs as one of the built-in service user accounts: SYSTEM, LOCALSERVICE or NETWORKSERVICE. These are not interactive users.

Your design is fundamentally flawed and I suspect you will need to move these settings into a file which is not part of a user profile.

Comment: @David. From one dificulty to another, for security reasons I need them in Registry. But somewhere I've seen Microsoft to tell us that we can read registry values from a service!!

Comment: @David. Please I'm here to listen any suggestions cover security and functionality, Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, What are your security considerations? I don't know anything about your problem.

Comment: @David. Well now I have to tell you the basic reason of creating this service. There is a programm on the Internet which when it runs stops the charge in some machines that I have (game machines). Thus I need this service in order to Kill this pirate process. And because the Kids are very much "worms" (with the good sence of the word, I have to develop some tricky actions in order to make there search more dificult.

Comment: @Lefteris Without wishing to sound rude, but I suspect that the author of the malicious software is more adept at this than you are. They will have no trouble at all working around anything you try. You need to consult an expert I expect.

Comment: @David. thats true, but they will made there own and we'll made our own and the life will go on. We have something to play for. If in case they made our lifes miserable then we will stand all together to find something for them. I believe that the experts are not so far away from us, we're close at least. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Is your service running as the same user as the Windows Forms application? If not, set it to run as the same user.

You will have to store it as CurrentMachine.

Comment: Oh tha is SOMETHING i never checked. because the service run as `Local System Account` and my windows form run as my user name. Basically I don't want to change anything from those.

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinins, then that's your problem then.  If you store something in CurrentUser (and you are definitely not running LocalSystem, which is only a system account that you do not log into), you won't see it in another account which the service is running on.  The answer is correct, LocalMachine is used for exactly this purpose.  However, the other answer is also correct -- you have to be careful about security considerations.  A hacker who is capable enough to write malware that circumvents your charging mechanisms will have zero difficulties in finding and changing these registry loc.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to access the registry key `CurrentUser` from windows services, I solved the same problem using `LocalMachine` key and `OpenBaseKey` method

```
RegistryKey rb =
    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey rb2 = rb.OpenSubKey(@"[KEYPATH]");
```

Only replace `KEYPATH` to your path key.

Check it in: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97ef477c-5f7e-473b-87bb-8a6a17876e6f/reading-registry-when-running-as-service?forum=csharpgeneral).